# Rename small part of multiple files in middle of name using Bash?

Tags: bash

I'd just like to change this

```
cc211_AMBER_13062012i.II  cc211_GROMOS_13062012i.II
cc211_CHARM_13062012i.II  cc211_OPLS_13062012i.II
```

to

```
cc211_AMBER_15062012i.II  cc211_GROMOS_15062012i.II
cc211_CHARM_15062012i.II  cc211_OPLS_15062012i.II
```

I tried,

```
find -name "*.13 *" | xargs rename ".13" ".15"
```

There is normally no space between the 3 and the second asterix, thats just makes it italics on from what I can see. Basically there's a lot of answers for what to do when it's at the end of the filename, where asterix seem to work, but here I can't make it work.

Anything you've got would make my life a lot easier!

Edit 1: Trial

```
-bash-4.1$ ls

cc211_AMBER_13062012.II  cc211_GROMOS_13062012.II
cc211_CHARM_13062012.II  cc211_OPLS_13062012.II

-bash-4.1$ rename 's/_13/_15/' cc*
-bash-4.1$ ls

cc211_AMBER_13062012.II  cc211_GROMOS_13062012.II
cc211_CHARM_13062012.II  cc211_OPLS_13062012.II
```

Comment: Why `rename ".13" ".15"` instead of `rename "_13" "_15"`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about this:

```
for i in *.II; do mv $i $(echo $i | sed 's/_13/_15/g'); done
```

This will replace `_13` with `_15` in all files with extension `.II`

More information on sed [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Answer (score 21):

A pure `bash` solution:

```
for i in cc*; do
  mv "$i" "${i/_13/_15}"
done
```

Comment: I would suggest to add quotes like this so there is no problem with spaces in filenames:
for i in cc*; do mv "$i" "${i/_13/_15}"; done

Comment: @user234461 No, parameter expansions use glob patterns, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 8):

```
rename 's/_13/_15/' cc*
```

Should do what you want. The regular expression `s/_13/_15/` replaces `_13` by `_15` in all files starting 'cc'.

```
$ ls
cc211_AMBER_13062012.II  cc211_GROMOS_13062012.II
cc211_CHARM_13062012.II  cc211_OPLS_13062012.II

$ rename 's/_13/_15/' cc*

$ ls
cc211_AMBER_15062012.II  cc211_GROMOS_15062012.II
cc211_CHARM_15062012.II  cc211_OPLS_15062012.II
```

This will only work with the newer perl version of `rename`. To check which version you have do `man rename`. If the top of the page says

> Perl Programmers Reference Guide

you have the perl version. If it says:

> Linux Programmer's Manual

you have the standard (older) version.

For the older version, the command should be:

```
rename _13 _15 cc*
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work on my shell, see Edit 1? What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think we have different versions of the `rename` command. I've edited my answer with more details, hope it helps!

Comment: `rename` is a command line tool in the perl package, also known as `prename`.It can use infinitely complex perl expression, so `prename -n 'use LWP::Simple;my $http=get("http://airport-authority.com/browse-FR");while($http=~m/>([^<>]+)<\/a> \((\w\w\w)\)/gc){my $from=$2;my $to=$1;$to=~s/ /_/g;s/$from/$to/g};' MRS_DOLLY_PARTON.MP3 PUFF_DADDY.MP3` will rename three letter codes in file names to French air port names with underscores, in this case the two MP3s are renamed `Marseille_Airport_St_Gatien_AirportLY_PARTON.MP3` and `Uzein_AirportF_DADDY.MP3`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a pure Linux solution:

```
### find all files that contains _DES in name and duplicate them adding _AUXLOCAL
for f in **/*_DES*; do
    cp "$f" "${f%.DES}_AUXLOCAL"
done 
###Rename all _AUXLOCAL files, removing _DES to _LOCAL
for f in **/*_AUXLOCAL*; do
  mv "$f" "${f/_DES/_LOCAL}"
done
###Rename all _AUXLOCAL files, removing _AUXLOCAL
for f in **/*_AUXLOCAL*; do
  mv "$f" "${f/_AUXLOCAL/}"
done
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use this command:

```
rename -v "_130" "_150" *.II
```